# How to display product category in custom developed theme?

Tags: php

I'm very new to wordpress. I found online that we can use shortcode to include product category. But My problem is, I developed custom theme. So my home page is empty in backend. I can't really access the custom homepage html via backend. SO how can I add the product category using shortcode?

Or is there a reference where can include it via php?